# AOP AspectJ static field initialization with Annotated (marked) Classes

Tags: java, static, annotations, aop, aspectj

I have a static field `public static Class[] items;` I want it to be filled at the start of the application with classes which have `@ItemExample` annotaion. Example classes(simplified):

```
public class ItemUtil{
public static Class[] itemClasses;
public static void actionsWithAllItemClasses(
//call some general method of classes in array using reflection API
)
}



  @ItemExample
    public class Item1 extends GeneralItem{
     public static void generalMethod(){
    //Item 1 specific action
        }
    }

    @ItemExample
    public class Item2 extends GeneralItem{
    public static void generalMethod(){
    //Item2 specific action
         }
    }
```

So at the starting(deployment, before ServletCOntextListneres start executing) time of application (Run in Tomcat) `item classes=={Item1.class, Item2.class}`. Also I would like each class to override the `generalMethod()` of `GeneralItem`, but this method is static, so each class declares it's own method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) Runtime search and

[Evo Class Index](http://www.atteo.org/blog/evo-class-index) Compile Time search

Helped.